# how to generate welcome screen

Tags: server, login, login-screen

when I login to my server, I see a  nice little welcome screen that tells me everything I want to know about how things are going. Memory use, updates if any, logged in users, sytem load, etc...

> Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-44-generic i686)
>
> - Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
>
>   System information as of Thu Jan 15 14:52:52 EST 2015
>
>   System load:  0.0                 Processes:           167   Usage
>     of /:   14.9% of 912.62GB   Users logged in:     1   Memory usage: 29%
>     IP address for eth0: 1.1.1.1   Swap usage:   0%
>
>   Graph this data and manage this system at:
>     https://landscape.canonical.com/
>
> 14 packages can be updated. 7 updates are security updates.
>
> Last login: Thu Jan 15 06:03:10 2015 from os.maine.edu

So, how do I generate this at some other time? (Without needing to log out and log back in)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called the "message of the day" or [motd](http://linux.die.net/man/5/motd) and by default is stored in `/etc/motd`. It is a bash script so all you need to do is execute it.

In case you want to add your own use `/etc/motd.tail`. [More details here](http://www.howtogeek.com/104708/how-to-customize-ubuntus-message-of-the-day/) and from the link:

> Let’s say you want to add a custom message users will see when they log into your Ubuntu system. Ubuntu’s MOTD is generated by scripts when you log in, so you can’t just add it to the /etc/motd file. The place to put your own static messages is /etc/motd.tail — the contents of this file are added to the end of the MOTD when it’s generated.

Comment: On ubuntu server 20.04, the script to generate this information is /usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper